# How to go through the array halfway and then continue from the end of the array to the half array?

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop

I'm trying to loop through the array, so that we take the first two values from the array at once, then the following iterations will take one value at a time until half of the array. When it comes to the middle of the field, it starts the same way, but from the end of the field towards the beginning. It takes first the last two values and then further iterations one value at a time to the center of the array.

I can do each part separately, the problem is putting it together

classic forward loop:

```
for i in a:
    print(i)
```

output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

reverse loop:

```
for i in reversed(a):
    print(i)
```

output:

```
6
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

a cycle that takes 2 values:

```
myList =np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
for x,y in (myList[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(myList),2)):
        print(x,y)
```

output:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

reverse loop:

```
for x,y in (myList[i:i+2] for i in reversed(range(0,len(myList),2))):
        print(x,y)
```

output:

```
5 6
3 4
1 2
```

---

I would need such an output
example

```
a=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
```

output

```
1 2
3
4
7 8 #or 8 7
6
5
```

or

```
a=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,])
```

output:

```
1 2  #or 1 2
3       #3
7 6     #4
5       #7 6
4       #5
```

the array can be of different sizes without restriction.

It is possible?

Comment: There are a couple edge cases. What do you do for short arrays? (length less than 5). How do you select the "middle"? Is it the 2nd in a list of 5 or the 3rd?

Comment: the array can be of different sizes without restriction

Comment: How would you imagine a `for` loop that sometimes produces one value, and sometimes two? Do you really want it to sometimes produce a tuple of two ints, and then in the next iteration a single int?

Comment: I do not know, so I ask if it is possible or is another way

Answer (score 0):

You can see the problem like that

- each group of values is printed the same way
- you apply to the first half and to the second half in reverse

```
def print_half(half_values):
    print(*half_values[:2])
    print(*half_values[2:], sep="\n")


def print_array(values):
    print_half(values[:len(values) // 2])
    print_half(list(reversed(values[len(values) // 2:])))


print_array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
print_array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way I can see is by storing a current index. First, the current index is `0`, and after the first step it is set to `2` (first 2 items). Then, we keep incrementing while `current_index < len // 2`, at which point we set `current_index = len - 1` and while `current_index > len // 2` we decrement.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
def printArr(List):
     for i in range(len(List)):
          if i < 2:
               print(List[i], end=' ')
               continue
          elif i == 2:
               print('\n', end='')
          print(List[i])

a=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,])
midle = int(len(a) / 2)
list1, list2 = a[:midle], a[-1: midle-1: -1]
printArr(list1)
printArr(list2)
```